# How to get "original" offset().top of a fixed element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, sticky

I am creating a StickyNav that should be fixed when the window scroll reaches the stickyNav's offset().top (nothing new here).

I cache the StickyNav's offset().top on page load, but this variable is not the same for mobile and desktop, so when I resize the screen this StickyNav gets "fixed" at a different point (depending if I first load the page on mobile or desktop)

My current work-around for this is to update this offset().top variable on window resize by doing something like this>

```
getOffSetTop : function(){
    var stickyNavBar = $(document).find('.stickynav');
    var offSetTop = stickyNavBar.offset().top;
    if(stickyNavBar.hasClass('fixed')){
        stickyNavBar.removeClass('fixed');
        offSetTop = $('.stickynav').offset().top;
        stickyNavBar.me.addClass('fixed');
    }
    return offSetTop;
}
```

Which works, but I don't know if there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a shortened version:

`if(typeof($(".stickyNavBar.fixed")) != undefined)`

`return $("stickyNavBar.fixed").offset().top`

`else`

`return 0:`

Sorry for the poor formatting, on mobile.

Comment: Hi Lewis!, Thanks for your reply, gives me a hint on how to better my code.